# sort-array not working where am I going wrong?

Tags: javascript

**Edit:** https://codesandbox.io/s/sort-array-965et - Seems to be working fine once I added every single value of Postdate into the slot order variable.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/sort-array
https://cache1.phantombooster.com/YRrbtT9qhg0/KJhwG7zo0zPE5zc9Eehn6Q/result.json - Objects im sorting

```
const slotOrder = ['1d','2d','3d','4d','5d','6d','1w','2w','3w','1m','2mo','3mo','4mo','5mo','6mo','7mo','8mo','9mo','10mo','11mo','1yr'];
selectedProfile = this.state.profiles; 
selectedProfile = sortBy(selectedProfile, 'postDate', { postDate: slotOrder })
```

Am I doing this correctly? As it does not seem to be sorting it the order is still pretty random :/

I would expect the posts with postDate 1d would be first then 2d etc etc

Comment: do you get the wanted result? what happens?

Comment: Whats the error you are getting

Comment: based on the API return, shouldn't you be sorting based on `timestamp`? The `postDate` sometimes is empty, which could cause problems as well as when it's an hourly post it says '10hr'

Comment: The timestamp is when the api grabs the linked in posts, not the post date :( I was going to not order the ones below 24 hours also. Proberly should add 1h,2h,3h though.

Comment: that is the weirdest timestamp I've ever seen.  Create a jsfiddle so we can investigate

Comment: Ok will do it now!

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/sort-array-965et - It seems to be working fine here!

Comment: Good, but locally still the same error? Try using comparing both results  from codesandbox and your local version to see if ther esults are the same?

Comment: @gugateider Ahh wait its not re-ordering them still :(

Comment: What I see from your code is that on your code for '1 month', you have `1m` but it should read `1mo`  which is not found on your list of order. I think if you fix that it will work as you wish

Comment: @gugateider you the man!